# Swift - Firebase getting all keys and store them into array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this firebase Database Structure:

```
Main
----- Name 1
--------value 1
--------value 2
--------value 3
----- Name 2
--------value 1
--------value 1
--------value 1
```

I'm trying to get all the key values and storing into an array of a custom class.

My custom class has an init:

```
init(name: String, photo: String) {
self._name = name
self._photo = photo
}
```

So in my View controller I have:

```
var array = [customClass]()
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Main")

func getInfo(){
    Ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        var arrayTemp = [customClass]()
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let name = snap.key
            let custom = customClass(Name: name, photo: "")
            arrayTemp.append(custom)
        }
        self.array = arrayTemp
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? Cell {
        let custom: Custom!
            custom = array[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(custom)
              return cell
    } else {
    return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

and here is the cell:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var Thumb: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var NameLbl: UILabel!

var custom: CustomClass!


func configureCell(_ custom: customClass) {

    self.custom = custom
    NameLbl.text = self.custom.customName.capitalized
    var url = URL(string: self.custom.photoUrl)
    if url == nil {
        url = URL(string: "")
    }
    Thumb.sd_setImage(with: url)

}
```

}

My issue is that if i print name I have all the values from the Db but when I reload the collection View I see the number of item correct but the name is just the first element repeated x time...
Any help?

Comment: Can you show us your cellForItemAtIndexPath function ?

Comment: @Pipiks thx for answering... i've update the question

Comment: In your cellForItemAtIndexPath and in your configureCell, the custom.customName is correct if you print it or not ?

Comment: @Pipiks no it gives me alway one and the same value repeated for the array count which is correct. so for now i have 3 items and i see 3 cell with the name "Name 1"

Comment: print(custom.customName) return always "Name 1" in your cellForItem ?

Comment: @Pipiks yes exactly.... this is because it seem that the array is populated just with the first element.... even if when i print snap.key i get the right results

Comment: Weird, and if you print(custom.customName)  before arrayTemp.append(custom) ?

Comment: @Pipiks well i't empty because the value should be added upon observing from firebase... so i have no value in it until the func is called and completed

Comment: print(custom.customName) just before the line arrayTemp.append(custom) not before the func

Comment: Sorry didn't understand... I get this: [app.customclass]  [app.customclass,app.customclass]  [app.customclass, app.customclass, app.customclass] this happens if I print the array...if I print the custom.name is nil. And I print the snap.key then I get the 3 correct values

Comment: Your custom name is a string or not ?

Comment: yea is a string

Comment: I have posted the question this morning also... here' s the link... maybe there are more info there...

Comment: It was all my bad!!!! i cannot believe i lost like almost a day on it!!!!!! the issue was so stupid... i've inverted numberOfSections and numberOfItemsInSection... was returning 1 in numberOfItemsInSection instead that in numberOfSections.. can't believe it!!!! thx anyway! :)

Comment: Ah ah ok, but now you know why we need the maximum code to fix your issue. You're welcome :)

Comment: i guess i do!! thx a lot! :)

Comment: I added the answer to close this question :)

Comment: Thanks! i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue :

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.array.count
}
```